# Python: I have a string like this [3000,0.17],[3050,0.17],[3100,0.01] and would like to convert it to a list

Tags: python, string, list

Elements of the list should be:
'[3000,0.17]','[3050,0.17]','[3100,0.01]' to my understanding I cannot use .split(','). Data is from a random json.file and I would like to have only the numbers.

Part of the file:
"line": {
"mbar":{'data': {'decX': 1, 'decY': 2, 'unX': 'mar', 'unY': 'min', 'poi': [[3000, 0.17], [3050, 0.17], [3100, 0.01]]}, 'svgurl': 'http://127.0.0.1:568/sg/save.min'}
},

What I did so far:

```
enter code here
with open('Test.json') as json_file:  
data = json.load(json_file) 

test = data['line'] 
result = json.dumps(test)
result.replace("mbar":{'data': {'decX': 1, 'decY': 2, 'unX': 'mar', 'unY': 
'min', 'poi':'))
new_result = result[result.rfind("[["):]
new_result1 = new_result[:new_result.rfind("},")]
new_result2 = new_result1.replace('[[','[')
new_result3 = new_result2.replace(']]',']')
```

I end up with this
[3000,0.17],[3050,0.17],[3100,0.01]

Comment: Are you trying to find something like `eval('[3000,0.17]')` ?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide example input/output and attempts to solve the issue and problems/exceptions you found.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Yes, but this converts it i a tuple and I would still like to edit it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your string is this:

```
tmp = '[3000,0.17],[3050,0.17],[3100,0.01]'
```

You can attach `[` on the front and `]` on the back, to get

```
'[[3000, 0.17], [3050, 0.17], [3100, 0.01]]'
```

You can do this either by adding strings with `+`: `'[' + tmp + ']'` or you can use f-strings: `f'[{tmp}]'`

Then you can use `json` to convert that to list of lists:

```
import json
tmp_list = json.loads(f'[{tmp}]')
```

This way, `tmp_list` will be:

```
[
    [3000, 0.17],
    [3050, 0.17],
    [3100, 0.01]
]
```

If you want a list of three strings, you can use list comprehension:

```
tmp_list = [str(item) for item in tmp_list]
```

And now your `tmp_list` is:

```
['[3000, 0.17]', '[3050, 0.17]', '[3100, 0.01]']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to USE split.

```
start_value = '[3000,0.17],[3050,0.17],[3100,0.01]'
output = []
tmp = ""
for e,s in enumerate(start_value.split(",")):
    if e % 2 == 0: # if e is even (even represents first value inside string list)
        tmp += s # append to tmp variable
    else:
        tmp += ","+s # for odd values (second part of string list), append comma with value because we are using comma as split delimiter
        output.append(tmp)
        tmp = ""
print(output)
```

Output will be
`>>> ['[3000,0.17]', '[3050,0.17]', '[3100,0.01]']`